# Encriptar BBDD MySQL con certificado

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, encriptación

¿Es posible encriptar una base de datos MySQL con un certificado, para que solo se pueda ver su contenido en el servidor donde esté instalado el certificado?

La idea es codificar toda la base de datos de golpe, para no tener que modificar consulta por consulta. Se que en SQL Server es posible, por eso me surge la duda de si en MySQL es posible.

**Edit 1**

He estado indagando por internet y he visto que hay una manera de hacerlo para lo que busco, TDE. ¿Es lo correcto?

**Edit 2**

Tras realizar una bateria de pruebas, veo que la BBDD debe estar en MySQL y las tablas en InnoDB, lo cuál es correcto, están así, pero al lanzar el comando de codificar la tabla, me aparece un error del plugin, que si que esta cargado, pero parece que no correctamente.

```
/* Consulta de encriptacion de tabla existente */
ALTER TABLE tabla ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

[image: Error plugin keyring]

Estoy accediendo desde un usuario root para lanzar las consultas, pero no parece que ese sea el problema (sino, lo informa)

Comment: Creo que esto es una buena referencia, no es un respuesta concreta pero posiblemente de una luz: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142289/open-source-cheap-data-at-rest-encryption-solutions

Comment: Gracias, el apartado de MySQL + InnoDB es el que había estado probando, pero ahora al lanzar la consulta me da el siguiente error y la verdad que hay muy poca información de como solucionarlo (lo pongo en la pregunta principal)